# Proof of range of converging sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $(a_n)$ be a sequence for which we know that $\lim_{n\to+\infty} a_n = 9$. Show that
we can find some positive integer $K$ such that for every $n\geqslant K$ it holds $8.996 < a_n < 9.0005$.

How would we prove this? Or at least show it? I've tried for a while (using first definition of limits, then induction (or something like that) but i haven't made much progress. Thanks!

Comment: What is the definition of convergence of a sequence? Once you check this out, you are done

Comment: Let $\epsilon = 0.0005$ and $K=n_0$, if you know what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

It's a definition.  The question is quizing your comprehension.

The definition of a $\lim_{n\to+\infty} a_n = b$ means that "$a_n$ gets close to $b$" which means: for any close distance $\epsilon$ all there is a point where all the $a_n$ are  within that distance from $b$, for sufficiently big enough values of $n$.  Or Formally

$\lim_{n\to+\infty} a_n = b$ is defined to mean that for all $\epsilon > 0$ we can a number $N_\epsilon$ (the sub epsilon isn't always part of the definition but I like to put it in to show that the N value is based on the $\epsilon$ value) such that for all the $n > N_\epsilon, |b - b_n| < \epsilon$.

So for any value of $\epsilon >$, say .0005 we can find some point where all the $a_n$s are within .0005 of 9.  We'll call that point K so that for all the $n > K$ then $a_n$ is within .0005 of 9.

In other words, for $\epsilon = .0005 > 0$, there is a number K such that for all $n > K$, $|9 - a_n| < .0005$.  So all $8.994 < 8.9995 < a_n <  9.0005$.

That's what the definition of what a limit is.

=====

Okay, *one* thing you have to show is that as you are trying to that the $a_n$s need to be within .0005 on one side but only .004 or the other so what epsilon do you pick.  Well, as you need to get within the range of the smaller value always pick epsilon to be the smaller value.